# History of Education Economics

Tags: reference-request, history, education-economics

I am looking for an historical overview about education economics covering especially the 20th century, e.g. the [randomized experiments beginning in the 1960s](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/21852490/)  or the [early](http://hanushek.stanford.edu/sites/default/files/publications/Hanushek%201971%20AER%2061%282%29_0.pdf) as well as [recent](https://pubs.aeaweb.org/doi/pdfplus/10.1257/aer.104.9.2593) attempts to measure teacher's value added. Any reference? Thank you!